# element width% based on PHP variable value

Tags: php, html, css

Consider the following:

```
$a=25;
$b=75;
```

I would like to show a percentage bar based on value of `$a` and `$b`. I would like to express the percentage bar as a div.

I guess I would need to do the following:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='a'></div>
    <div id='b'></div>
</div>

#container{
width: 100%
}

#a{
Width: $a //here I need to get the value of $a
}
```

Any Idea how I can implement this?

I need to get this in an `external stylesheet`.

What I hope to achieve, keep in mind that value of $a and $b varies

[image]

Comment: ^ Is this inline css or should that then be an external css file?

Comment: It should be external!!

Comment: You should mention that in the question.

Comment: It's not possible to add php in an external css file, you could however achieve it using javascript

Comment: @sgtBOSE Im sorry I forgot to mention that I will vote your answer up...but now you deleted it

Comment: you have to use internal css for this.

Comment: ok If it is not possible to do via external I guess I  have no choice but to go with inline

Comment: Note that as the answers indicate, it IS possible to use a PHP file as a CSS stylesheet. All you need to do is include `header('content-type: text/css');` at the very top. It's not efficient though.

Comment: @MrLister why not efficient?

Comment: @Marilee Because then the server will have two PHP to process, the main one for the HTML and the one for the CSS. (Real CSS files are served up as-is, without needing additional parsing.) So the server has to do twice as much work for for each page displayed to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use PHP variables in CSS files when you build (and save) them dynamically.  If the value changes often (when it depends on the page or the content for example), I would not recommend that. Instead you can perfectly use inline style blocks:

```
<style> #a { width: <php echo $a; ?>; } </style>
```

**Edit: added an example as requested in the comments:**

To make sure all elements have 100% of their container's width, just substract `$t1` from 100:

```
<?php
    $width_t1 = 25;
    $style_t1 = 'float: left; width: ' . $width_t1 . '%; height:50px;';
    $width_t2 = 100 - $width_t1;
    $style_t2 = 'float: left; width: ' . $width_t2 . '%;';

    if ($count > 0) {
        $style_t1 .= ' background-color: red';
    } else {
        $style_t1 .= ' background-color: blue';
    }
?>
<div id="t1" style="<?php echo $style_t1; ?>">...</div>
<div id="t2" style="<?php echo $style_t2; ?>">...</div>
```

Comment: ok this is what I did:`if($count>0){
     echo'<div id="t1" style="width:'.$t1.'%; float:left; height:50px; background-color:red">';   
    }
    else{  
    echo'<div id="t1" style="width:'.$t1.'%; float:left; height:50px; background-color:blue">';`

Comment: but now How can I ensure that the bar will always add up to 100% since $t1 varies and not out of 100